# How to make a bad words filter in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a bad words filter with my bot in discord.js v13 and node.js v16.

When I send a 'word1' message, It works correctly and deletes the message. but when I send for example: "Hey word1", It does not delete the message.

What I've tried:

```js
const args = message.content.split(/ +/);
if ((message.guild.id = 'GUILD_ID')) {
  const bad = ['word1', 'word2'];
  if (bad.includes(args[0].join(' '))) {
    message.delete();
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you check if the array contains the string `"Hello word1"`.

You can use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a callback function to check if the string contains any of those words in the array:

```js
function containsBadWords(str) {
  const badWords = ['word1', 'word2']

  if (badWords.some(word => str.toLowerCase().includes(word))) 
    return 'String contains bad words'
  else 
    return 'No bad words found'
}

console.log(containsBadWords('word1'))
console.log(containsBadWords('Some other text that includes word2 here'))
console.log(containsBadWords('No bad words here'))
```

```js
// make sure you don't use single '=' here!
if (message.guild.id === 'GUILD_ID') {
  const bad = ['word1', 'word2']
  if (bad.some(word => message.content.includes(word)))
    message.delete()
  else
    return
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for sharing. I replaced the code you shared with mine with some edits: 
```js
if (message.guild.id === '847071265100791849'){
const fosh = ['words1', 'word2'];
if (fosh.some(word => args[0].join(' ').includes(word))){
message.delete();
} else {
return;
}```


But it returns an error: ```err
args[0].join is not a function
```

Comment: Ah, yes, `args[0]` is a string, it should be `args.join()`, or simply `message.content`. I'm just updating my answer with it.